# Javascript Object constructor not grouping items together

Tags: javascript

New to js object constructor and while I was reading about the subject, I cam accross this example. I used it to add items to a hypothetical product page and it works except when I add the same item twice, it groups the item and just increase the qty. What if I don't want to group the items.

```
function Cart(oldcart) {
  this.items = oldcart.items || {};

  this.add = function (item, id) {
    var storeditem = this.items[id];
    if (!storeditem) {
      storeditem = this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 };
    }
    storeditem.qty++;
    storeditem.price = storeditem.item.itemprice * storeditem.qty;
  };
}

var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});
cart.add(data, id);
req.session.cart = cart;
```

My understading of the code is that it checks if this.items has the id of the newly added item

```
var storeditem = this.items[id];
```

and if not, then create the item

```
if (!storeditem) {
  storeditem = this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 };
}
```

But if I don't want to group items together and I just want the items to be listed separately, how do I do that inside the this.add method? When I do this :

```
this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 };
```

it replaces the old item with the new one. What am I doing wrong? Please don't tell me to do it with jquery which is a great tool but I'd like to learn how to do it in pure js.

Comment: You are using an `id` as your key. Based on this code, if you want to list them separately, you have to use a new `id` or index them differently. Also, if the purpose is to list everything separately, I'd suggest to just keep an array and push to that array instead of using an object. Also, most probably the `quantity` property would be irrelevant in that case.

Comment: Can you explain what your expected result is? I am not sure I understand it given this code. `this.items[id]` allows you to only have one entry per ID. You can have *an array* for each ID or perhaps just keep `this.items` as an array and not index by ID. Or perhaps even keep the code but convert the dictionary for display replacing the quantities to a flat list with repeating items.

Comment: @JonathanHamel Thanks. True. If I push to an array separately, then no need to qty. I have options that the user will add to some items and some items have no options, so I would group the items with no options and separate items that the user will customize with options separately as a list and that is why I added the qty there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're storing every new item in an object. If you want a list of every seperate item, then switch to an array. So `this.items` should be an array to start with.

In the `add` method, use the `push` method on `this.items` to add a new item to the array. Now you'll have added your item to the list. From here you can do things like calculating the total price, by looping over the list and adding all of the `itemprice` values together.

```js
function Cart(oldcart) {
  this.items = oldcart.items || [];
  this.total = oldcart.total || 0;
} 

Cart.prototype.add = function(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
  this.total = this.items.reduce(function(total, currentItem) {
    return total + currentItem.itemprice;
  }, 0);
};

var cart = new Cart({});
cart.add({ id: 52, name: 'Melon', itemprice: 3.20 });
cart.add({ id: 2, name: 'Banana', itemprice: 0.30 });
cart.add({ id: 2, name: 'Banana', itemprice: 0.30 });

console.log('Cart items:', cart.items);
console.log('Price total:', cart.total);
```

Comment: Emiel, in your comment, you mentioned to store separate items in an array. In Object you could do that too, so why switch to an array?

Comment: Arrays are objects that specialize in handling lists. They come with a multitude of methods that allow you to loop over the items inside of it  [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You could also set each item to a new key in an object, but an array would do that for you, using integers as keys. Simply put, it's the right tool for the job.